# Hudson / Jenkins: share parameters between several jobs

Tags: jenkins, hudson, parameter-passing

I have about 20 jobs using common parameters (user, password), and sometimes the password expires... So I have to change it on all jobs, which is really time consuming (and error prone, I may forget one).

I thought about:

- using a kind of magic property file if that exists to have directly lines like KEY, VALUE added into job parameters
- adding the same kind of KEY, VALUE pair directly inside `build.xml`, but where ? And it's really ugly... Maybe with a dedicated XML embedded into the `build.xml` ?
- calling a slave job that would (how ?) push up to the parent one the desired values...

As you can see I'm only starting in Hudson/Jenkins (I'm using Jenkins 1.424.2.2), thanks for your help !

**EDIT:** I'm not admin of the Jenkins instance, so I cannot have access to global properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually succeeded by:

- keeping encrypted credentials in a web page
- retrieving them in Hudson thanks to a shell script (wget), decrypt them, and creating a `build.properties` file in the workspace with lines `name=value` (in my case `ssh.password=...`)

This works, because Ant build steps detect this file and pass the variables inside into their context. Thanks to that I could centralize my credentials.

Answer (score 7):

Go to your Jenkins home and navigate :

1. Manage Jenkins >
2. Configure System >
3. Global properties >
4. Environment variables > `....`

Comment: Good point: as I just edited, I'm not an admin so I can't use global properties (and admins won't let me play with them, for sure).

Comment: :( missed the edit in hurry. Anyways the 2nd approach by Anders seems the way to go right now; else we can call @Koshuke :)

Comment: Oh you did not miss it, I just added it because you talked about global properties :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches:

- Use *Global properties*, found under **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure system**. Here you can define environment variables that should be available to all jobs.
- Write a small script that downloads, modifies and posts the job config: `http://[jenkinshost]/job/[jobname]/config.xml`.

You can read about the api capabilities under `http://[jenkinshost]/job/[jobname]/api`, here is what it says about reading and changing config.xml:

> **Fetch/Update config.xml**
>
> To programmatically obtain config.xml, hit
>   `[http://[jenkinshost]/job/[jobname]/config.xml]`. You can also POST
>   an updated config.xml to the same URL to programmatically update the
>   configuration of a job.

Comment: As said above, I'm not admin, so I cannot access global properties; but the 2nd solution looks promising, let's see if I can manage to do what I want playing with it...